# How to find when qtranslate plugin's language changes?

Tags: multi-language, plugin-qtranslate

I used qtranslate for make my website multilingual, In fact this plugin just make an option for my content to has another translate, but how can i use it in my code?
for example:

```
if ( $language == "ar" ) {
 // somthing }
```

Comment: Are you referring to qTranslate ???

Comment: yes but i cant find any result

Answer (score 1):

From qTranslate's official support [forums](http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=9)

The function to get the current language is `qtrans_getLanguage()`